# Swap logical device names of two NVME SSD drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, devices, ssd, nvme

Is it possible to swap logical device names of two NVME SSD drives installed in a laptop (Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 2022) without phisically swapping their port positions?
I would like the current `/dev/nvme0n1` to become `/dev/nvme1n1` and vice versa.
If it's possible, how do I do this?
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04LTS.

Comment: you can't, usually, as these are derived from physical bus structure. It also sounds *a lot* as if you're trying to solve a problem that you would solve via some logical device manager, UUIDs or other approaches. So, please explain what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: I got installed second NVME SSD by the service, and my laptop returned with swapped logical device names... ie. the original SSD with Ubuntu is now `/dev/nvme1n1` and newly installed SSD is `/dev/nvme0n1`. I'm trying to figure out how that happened (did the servicer move the original SSD from one slot to another before installing a new one?) and can it be "fixed" without physically opening the laptop. I just don't want to be stuck with reversed logic where my main storage is indexed as 1, and secondary as 0 in years to come.

Comment: I think you're interpreting too much into the numbering – nothing in your system *cares* whether something is number 0 or number 1. Instead, refer to your storage devices by UUID, and you will never have a problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I'm a bit quirky about the numbers, ordering, etc... thanks for reassuring me that the system should continue to work just fine (what was my guess also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not entirely impossible to change the order, doing so won't solve any problem and will only create more, so you shouldn't do it.

Device names are assigned on a first come, first serve basis, which means the order can change anytime and *you should not rely on it at all*. Stick to (PART-) UUID/LABEL, one of the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-*/*`, or alternatively LVM device names (if you're using LVM).

So this is just for fun (tested in qemu with emulated nvme drives, not tested on real hardware).

---

Original detected order:

```
# grep nvme /proc/partitions
 259        0   16777216 nvme0n1
 259        1   33554432 nvme1n1
 259        2   67108864 nvme2n1
```

Changing order by unbinding, then binding in the desired order. Doing this removes the NVMe device from the system entirely and re-detects them from scratch. So it can only be done from initramfs, or when the device is not in use at all.

```
# ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/
0000:00:04.0  0000:00:05.0  0000:00:06.0  bind  [...]  unbind
# cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/
# echo 0000:00:04.0 > unbind
# echo 0000:00:05.0 > unbind
# echo 0000:00:06.0 > unbind
# echo 0000:00:06.0 > bind
# echo 0000:00:04.0 > bind
# echo 0000:00:05.0 > bind
```

New order (nvme2 » nvme0, nvme0 » nvme1, nvme1 » nvme2):

```
# grep nvme /proc/partitions
 259        0   67108864 nvme0n1
 259        1   16777216 nvme1n1
 259        2   33554432 nvme2n1
```

---

Normally this is not practical to do for any reason. That said I've used this method before on an embedded device that did not detect by itself when a microsd card was removed or changed.

So it might be possible it could help with NVMe in some situations (like when recovering a failing card) but I haven't had such a case yet so this is just in theory.

Comment: I've decided to leave everything as it is. Anyway, Although I won't test the answer I'm accepting it.